# What should I use to cover shower framing behind tile in a bathroom?

Tags: bathroom, repair, shower, tile, maintenance

I have this repair I have to do at work. I have an idea on what to do but I am not entire sure. My thoughts are to start with installing a wood board than drywall mud and than tile. Of course there would be more to it than just that but for time purposes I will just leave it at that for now. Please if anyone can help I would appreciate it.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have a moisture problem in there so I'd be staying away from installing any wood or drywall. There are also some bull nose tiles that will have to be replaced but you have acknowledged that this will be a repair in progress. You should think about using cement board and installing it so when you add the tiles to it, they will be flush with the other tiles.

Answer (score 2):

Drywall mud has no place under tile, IMHO. Given the cost and labor of tile, I don't think **drywall** has any place under tile, but that's not a well-accepted view for some reason.

Wood looks to be a poor choice there as well, given the rust on the steel stud that's exposed. Of course, if the water source isn't fixed that stud and its friends may fail later on.

Cementboard ("tile backer") and thinset and tile. If you need more thickness than one hunk of backer, use more than one and butter between them with thinset. There's more than one thickness of tile backer available, as well, if one isn't enough and two is too much.

You will probably need to remove more tile to get to undamaged backer-board to make a joint between the new and old properly (with the proper alkali-resistant backer-board mesh tape and thinset) - or you may not have backerboard there, perhaps it's drywall - still the broken edge extending back behind some of the side tiles means the side tiles need to be popped off to make a proper repair to the substrate before reattaching the tiles over the substrate.

Comment: thank you for your feedback. I am the maintenance man at a live-in treatment facility and this is how the previous maintenance man left things. This is in one of our shower/bathroom areas. I am planning on shutting down the bathrooms and working on them for about a week to get everything fixed. I have my hands full with a bunch of small stuff not to mention everything else. I have done some tile work but it has been a long time, and at that Ive never done tile work on walls nor in a bathroom. So as you can see I am in for a punishing few days. Thank you for the feedback it is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I repaired a similar issue with a residential shower.  Besides for fixing the tile wall, the other issue is standing or dripping water from the shower door wicking under the wall joint.

After you have repaired the wall, carefully inspect the shower door frame and curb for cracks in the grout.  Fill all that, and then silicone caulk the joints to prevent any water sneaking into the wall.

Comment: Good advice, but doesn't answer the question.